# Is there a way to make this code more concise?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am teaching myself javascript and am currently using Google Apps Script as a way to practice and create tools that I could use for myself.

I have created this script to prompted the user for input if a checkbox is check and insert the input into a cell, and if the checkbox is uncheck it will clear the associated cells.

I want to develop good coding habits starting out and would love for someone to review my code and see if there is a better or more concise solution.

```js
/* When checkboxes are edited, user will be prompted to enter data, which will be filled in the correlating cells */

function onEdit(e) {
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    
    //sets selected cell to currentCell
    var currentCell = e.source.getCurrentCell();
    
    //returns locations of currentCell
    var rowIndex = Number(currentCell.getRow());
    var columnIndex = Number(currentCell.getColumn());
    
    //If edits aren't being made on Inventory Management, do not continue. 
    if (sheet.getName() !== "Inventory Management") return;

    //Check if current cell is in column 10 aka Column J
    if (Number(currentCell.getColumn()) == 10) {
        
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        
        //Checks if action checks (True) or unchecks box (False)
        if (currentCell.getValue().toString() == "true") {

            var askingPrice = ui.prompt("Enter Asking Price ");
            
            //If user clicks close, do not continue. 
            if (askingPrice.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
                return;

            } else {
                
                //Sets location for column 11 (K) and column 12 (L)
                let priceColumn = columnIndex + 1;
                let dateColumn = columnIndex + 2;
                
                var datePosted = ui.prompt("Enter Date Posted (format: 'mm/dd/yyyy')");
                
                //Sets the users responses to the correlating cells
                sheet.getRange(rowIndex, priceColumn).setValue(Number(askingPrice.getResponseText()));
                sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateColumn).setValue(String(datePosted.getResponseText()));
            }
            
        //user unchecks box (false)  
        } else {
            
            //Sets location for column 11 (K) and column 12 (L)
            let priceColumn = columnIndex + 1;
            let dateColumn = columnIndex + 2;
            
            //clears values in correlating cells
            sheet.getRange(rowIndex, priceColumn).setValue("");
            sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateColumn).setValue("");
        }
    }
    
    //Check if current cell is in column 14 aka Column N
    if (Number(currentCell.getColumn()) == 14) {
        
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        
        //Checks if action checks (True) or unchecks box (False)
        if (currentCell.getValue().toString() == "true") {
            
            var soldPrice = ui.prompt("Enter Sold Price ");
            
            //If user clicks close, do not continue. 
            if (soldPrice.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
                return;

            } else {
            
                //Sets location for column 14 (O), column 15 (P) and 17 (R)
                let priceColumn = columnIndex + 1;
                let dateColumn = columnIndex + 2;
                let shipColumn = columnIndex + 4;

                var dateSold = ui.prompt("Enter Date Sold (format: 'mm/dd/yyyy')");
                var shipCost = ui.prompt("Enter Shipping Cost (if none, Enter 0)");
                
                //Sets the users responses to the correlating cells
                sheet.getRange(rowIndex, priceColumn).setValue(Number(soldPrice.getResponseText()));
                sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateColumn).setValue(String(dateSold.getResponseText()));
                sheet.getRange(rowIndex, shipColumn).setValue(String(shipCost.getResponseText()));
            }
            
        //user unchecks box (false) 
        } else {
        
            //Sets location for column 14 (O), column 15 (P) and 17 (R)
            let priceColumn = columnIndex + 1;
            let dateColumn = columnIndex + 2;
            let shipColumn = columnIndex + 4;

            //clears values in correlating cells
            sheet.getRange(rowIndex, priceColumn).setValue("");
            sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateColumn).setValue("");
            sheet.getRange(rowIndex, shipColumn).setValue("");
        }
    }
    
    //Check if current cell is in column 22 aka Column V
    if (Number(currentCell.getColumn()) == 22) {
        
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        
        ////Checks if action checks (True) or unchecks box (False)
        if (currentCell.getValue().toString() == "true") {
        
            var dateDonation = ui.prompt("Enter Date of Dontation");
            
            //If user clicks close, do not continue. 
            if (dateDonation.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
                return;

            } else {
            
                //Sets location for column 23 (W)
                let donationColumn = columnIndex + 1;
                
                //Sets the users responses to the correlating cells
                sheet.getRange(rowIndex, donationColumn).setValue(String(dateDonation.getResponseText()));
            }        
            
        //user unchecks box (false) 
        } else {
            
            //Sets location for column 23 (W)
            let donationColumn = columnIndex + 1;
            
            //clears values in correlating cells
            sheet.getRange(rowIndex, donationColumn).setValue("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to ask for code reviews.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that!

Comment: Have you read best practices? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    if (sheet.getName() !== "Inventory Management") return;
    if (Number(e.range.columnStart)==10) {
        if (e.value=="TRUE") {
            var askingPrice=ui.prompt("Enter Asking Price ");
            if (askingPrice.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
                return;
            } else {
                var datePosted = ui.prompt("Enter Date Posted (format: 'mm/dd/yyyy')");
                e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Number(askingPrice.getResponseText()));
                e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(String(datePosted.getResponseText()));
            }
        } else {
            e.range.offset(0,1).setValue("");
            e.range.offset(0,2).setValue("");
        }
    }
    if (e.range.columnStart==14) {
        
        if (e.value=="TRUE") {
            var soldPrice = ui.prompt("Enter Sold Price ");
            if (soldPrice.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
                return;
            } else {
                var dateSold = ui.prompt("Enter Date Sold (format: 'mm/dd/yyyy')");
                var shipCost = ui.prompt("Enter Shipping Cost (if none, Enter 0)");
                e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Number(soldPrice.getResponseText()));
                e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(String(dateSold.getResponseText()));
                e.range.offset(0,4).setValue(String(shipCost.getResponseText()));
            }
        } else {
            e.range.offset(0,1).setValue("");
            e.range.offset(0,2).setValue("");
            e.range.offset(0,4).setValue("");
        }
    }
    if (e.range.columnStart==22) {
        if (e.value=="TRUE") {
            var dateDonation = ui.prompt("Enter Date of Dontation");
            if (dateDonation.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
                return;
            } else {
                e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(String(dateDonation.getResponseText()));
            }        
        } else {
            e.range.offset(1,1).setValue("");
        }
    }
}
```